# border around inner divs in a outer div container

Tags: html, css, border, containers

I have the code at the following link [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3oxrdyug/). I want border just around the inner content, instead of stretching it.

Tried the following:

- clear fix with div
- Overflow:hidden for the container div

That did not work. It should work in IE8 and above, Chrome and FF.

HTML:

```
<div class="ptr" >
  <div><span>Program Type</span></div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="dc" checked>
      <span>Cust</span>
     <input type="radio" id="tu">
       <span>User</span>
     <input type="radio" id="b">
       <span>All</span>
   </div> 
   <div style="clear:both; line-height:0">&nbsp;</div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.ptr {
  border: 1px solid #bbccbb;
}
```

Comment: What does 'did not work' mean? What result do you want (a picture would be ideal), what's wrong with your current outcome?

Comment: Do you mean like this? = http://jsfiddle.net/3oxrdyug/5/

Comment: I think you need to have `display:inline` (or `display:inline-block` - try both) on your div class `ptr`.

Comment: @Paulie_D yes. The outer div/container spans entire width of the page and inner divs should be centered with border around them like you did

Comment: @DavidThomas Currently, the border wraps around the outer div which is 100%. I want the border around inner content, ignoring the spaces, while still being centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divs are `display:block` elements by default. So it will always take up the whole width available, unless you set otherwise. One way for that is to set it `display:inline-block`

```
div.program-type-row {
    border: 1px solid #bbccbb;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3oxrdyug/13/

**EDIT**

According to your comments bellow, you really need a wrapper to set the border around the content, despite the container's width... So wrap the content in a div, and set the `border` and `display:inline` properties to this wrapper, and center it setting the container as `text-align: center;`

http://jsfiddle.net/3oxrdyug/14/

HTML:

```
<div name="userTypeOptions" class="program-type-row" >
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div><span class="form-field label">Program Type</span></div>
      <div>
          <input type="radio" id="dwcust" name="userType" checked />
            <span class="form-field label">DW Customer</span>
            <input type="radio" id="tusr" name="userType" />
            <span class="form-field label">Trail User</span>
            <input type="radio" id="both" name="userType" />
           <span class="form-field label">All</span>
      </div> 
      <div style="clear:both; line-height:0">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.program-type-row {
    text-align: center;
}

#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #bbccbb;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: The container / outer div is 100% width and the inner divs should be centered. Can you update your JSFiddle link?

Comment: when I just set the width to 100%, its back to normal. The border is back to the outer div.

Comment: I already resorted to that solution. But anyways, thanks for the update! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should make a wrapper, containing the radio buttons.
Then give the wrapper 'display:table;' and the radio buttons 'display:table-cell' CSS-properties.

Your code would be as followed:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="radio">Button 1
    <input type="radio">Button 2
    <input type="radio">Button 3                  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    display:table;
    border:1px solid black;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

**Here a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3oxrdyug/12/)**